# Mail range with formatting through vba in excel

Tags: excel, outlook, range, mailing, vba

there are lot`s of articles in the web, how to pass excel range in the outlook mail. So i am using the following code:

```
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set rng = Sheets("Report").Range("A3:F" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").UsedRange.Rows.Count)

With OutMail
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)   
    .Display
End With
```

In my range i have table of hyperlinks. And i want them to be clickable in the email body. But they are not. I understand this, because the BodyFormat propherty is olFormatHTML. And if i change the BodyFormat to Plain or RichText,  hyperlinks become clickable but all the formatting crashes. How can i save all the formatting and make hyperlinks clickable in the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using Ron's [RangetoHTML](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail4.htm)

If yes then you have to add some extra code to it so that it retains the hyperlinks.

I have added the code and you can see the same between

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ADDED THIS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is the amended Code.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ADDED THIS ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim HyperL As Hyperlink
    For Each HyperL In rng.Hyperlinks
        TempWB.Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Range(HyperL.Range.Address), _
        Address:=HyperL.Address, _
        TextToDisplay:=HyperL.TextToDisplay
    Next HyperL
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First of all, there was a little mistake in your code(Next Hlink). I fix it, but the result is particulary the same. Hyperlinks are not clickable. Does your code work for you? Maybe there are some options in Outlook application?

Comment: Yes it works for me. Though you have to press CTL + Click to follow the hyperling. Updating a snapshot

Comment: And for me CTRL + CLick is not working( Only if i switch bodyformat to reach text(

Comment: I have updated the above post. I can confirm that it is working on my pc.

Comment: i am working in outlook 2003. Maybe there are some differences between two versions.

Comment: let me check in office 2003. Your excel version is also 2003?

Comment: Ok I checked Excel 2003 + Outlook 2003 and it is working on my pc.

Comment: can you please send the excel file to my mail. I`l be veeeery pleased.

Comment: I have uploaded the file in wikisend.com you can download it from here http://wikisend.com/download/116808/Sample.xls

Comment: O, i found it. there is a checkbox  "Use Microsoft Office Word 2003 to edit e-mail messages" in Options > Mail Format. If i turn it on, links became clickable.  Is it checked also in your oulook?

Comment: So here is the answer) But i think my users will not be happy, if i tell them to check something in outlook options. So i need to tick this checkbox through vba, but i haven`t found something usefull yet.

Comment: Now I have Siddharth's email address! MWAHAHAHAHA!

Comment: @JP: LOL Everyone has access to it from my blog (address in Profile)

Comment: @JP.: Ah I didn't know about that link...! Nice one! BTW the email mentioned above is actually an image ;)