# How to preserve/retain hyperlinks in email body when using RangetoHTML from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I am using Ron de Bruin's RangetoHTML example to send email from selection on current worksheet in Excel. All working perfectly, however the two columns of the sheet that contain hyperlinks are coming as plain text (and are not clickable).
I further tried to implement the suggestion from [Mail range with formatting through vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136214/mail-range-with-formatting-through-vba-in-excel) and added the "For Each HyperL" loop, but after doing that surprisingly the whole email body comes out completely empty. I can see that the temp file is not empty, but the hyperlinks are already missing there too.

below is my example - much appreciating ideas on what I have done wrong!

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim Hlink As Hyperlink

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    For Each Hlink In rng.Hyperlinks
        TempWB.Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Range(Hlink.Range.Address), _
        Address:=Hlink.Address, _
        TextToDisplay:=Hlink.TextToDisplay
    Next Hlink
 

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Here is the calling subroutine code:

```
Sub SendBugReport()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
            .to = Sheets("Email Subject and Dlist").Range("B1").Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Sheets("Email Subject and Dlist").Range("B5").Value
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(Source)
            .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    '    .Close savechanges:=False
 
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see anything there about email. Can you post the full code.

Comment: @GavinP, 
Thank you for reply
here is the subroutine code:

Comment: Actually added the subroutine code in the original question description

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped you were just using .Body instead of .HTMLBody. I'm wondering if you're over complicating it with the htm file creation etc. Is the only value in the 2 columns a link? Could you simply iterate through the range creating the email body a line at a time, in a table  adding the required HTML tags?

Comment: @GavinP, thanks for reply - I saw this suggestion in another post, but I am not finding it easier or more simple to run a double cycle and add html tags manually. I have 2 columns at this time that hold hyperlinks. Isn't there a way to make it work with the above approach? Thanks so much!

Comment: How big is the range of links? That may be a limiting factor, but if you just need the email body to be in a tabular format of `link one | link 2` then yes, I think you could dispense with the first part entirely.

Comment: My table consists of 11 columns, 2 of which contain hyperlinks. (And there is also content before and after the table which is not in tabular format but I guess that is not important).

Comment: And I need the table nicely formatted with borders, etc.

Comment: OK, that sounds eminently doable. You just need to be able to iterate through the range, add the appropriate HTML tags to table and format it. Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: I am sure you are right and it is doable. It's just that I find it elegant that there is a solution that makes html from excel not "manually" but "automatically", just not getting it why it would not retain the hyperlinks. Thanks for your input anyway

Comment: I am not suggesting in any way that you make the process "manual". I am not familiar with the code in the original post or the link you gave. What I suggested is essentially redoing that which may be redundant. I have no idea why your code isn't working as written, sorry. Try putting a breakpoint on your rangetohtml and step through to see what it's actually doing and where the output is set to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the [following link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/560111-retain-hyperlinks-after-rangetohtml-paste-outlook.html) which will help in this.

As a summary, adding the following in `RangeToHTML()` will suffice:

At the top:

```
Dim Hlink As Hyperlink
```

Just before publish code:

```
For Each Hlink In rng.Hyperlinks
TempWB.Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add _
Anchor:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Range(Hlink.Range.Address), _
Address:=Hlink.Address, _
TextToDisplay:=Hlink.TextToDisplay
Next Hlink
```

Answer (score 0):

When building the temp file, rather than using the paste values in the code,

- column widths, values, formats

Replace by using the following past value combo:

- column widths, and ALL

I've left in the values and format lines (commented out) so you can see the placement.

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, , False, False
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```